# Dependency issue with Azure Bicep resource modules

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-bicep

I am creating three resources: cosmos account, cosmos database, and cosmos containers. I have all of them within one folder except for the containers where I modularized it.

main.bicep

```
// Cosmos DB Account
resource cosmos 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts@2020-06-01-preview' = if (deployDB) {
  name: cosmosAccountName
  location: location
  tags: appTags
  kind: 'GlobalDocumentDB'
  identity: {
    type: 'None'
  }
  properties: {
  ...
  }
  dependsOn: [
    virtualNetwork
  ]
}

// Cosmos SQL Database
resource cosmosdb 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases@2020-04-01' = if (deployDB) {
  name: '${cosmos.name}/${databaseName}'
  properties: {
    resource: {
      id: databaseName
    }
    options: {
      throughput: 400
    }
  }
}


// Cosmos DB Containers
module cosmosContainersUser '../../../cicd/bicep/modules/datastore/cosmos-db.bicep' = [for container in cosmosContainers: if (deployDB) {
  name: container.containerName
  params: {
    cosmosContainerName: container.name
    id: container.id
    partitionKey: container.partitionKey
  }
}]
```

cosmos-db.bicep

```
param cosmosContainerName string
param id string
param partitionKey string

// Cosmos Containers
resource cosmosContainerUser 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers@2021-06-15' = {
  name: cosmosContainerName
  properties: {
    resource: {
      id: id
      indexingPolicy: {
        indexingMode: 'consistent'
        automatic: true
        includedPaths:[
          {
            path: '/*'
          }
        ]
        excludedPaths: [
          {
            path: '/"_etag"/?'
          }
        ]
      }
      partitionKey: {
        kind: 'Hash'
        paths: [
          partitionKey
        ]
      } 
      conflictResolutionPolicy: {
        mode: 'LastWriterWins'
        conflictResolutionPath: '/_ts'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works no problem however main.bicep is still massive and I want to keep modularizing it and am having trouble moving the other resources into cosmos-db.bicep. If I was to add the cosmos database resource into the file:

cosmos-db.bicep

```
param databaseName string
param cosmosDbName string
param cosmosContainerName string
param id string
param partitionKey string

// Cosmos Database
resource cosmosdb 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases@2020-04-01' = {
  name: cosmosDbName
  properties: {
    resource: {
      id: databaseName
    }
    options: {
      throughput: 400
    }
  }
}

// Cosmos Containers
resource cosmosContainerUser 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers@2021-06-15' = {
  name: cosmosContainerName
  properties: {
    resource: {
      id: id
      indexingPolicy: {
        indexingMode: 'consistent'
        automatic: true
        includedPaths:[
          {
            path: '/*'
          }
        ]
        excludedPaths: [
          {
            path: '/"_etag"/?'
          }
        ]
      }
      partitionKey: {
        kind: 'Hash'
        paths: [
          partitionKey
        ]
      } 
      conflictResolutionPolicy: {
        mode: 'LastWriterWins'
        conflictResolutionPath: '/_ts'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

main.bicep

```
module cosmosdb '../../../cicd/bicep/modules/datastore/cosmos-db.bicep' = {
  name: 'cosmosDbName'
  params: {
    cosmosDbName: 'cosmosDbName'
    databaseName: databaseName
  }
}
```

I get a red line under the `params` keyword in both cosmosdb and cosmosContainersUser modules in main.bicep. For cosmosdb module it says: `The specified "object" declaration is missing the following required properties: "cosmosContainerName", "id", "partitionKey".bicep(BCP035)` and the `params` keyword in cosmosContainersUser module says `The specified "object" declaration is missing the following required properties: "cosmosDbName", "databaseName".bicep(BCP035)`.

I'm guessing this is a dependency issue since these resources rely on one another. I can't use the parent key word in main.bicep because modules don't support it. I try to use `dependsOn` and I tried adding parent to the cosmosContainerUser in cosmos-db.bicep and still get the same error messages.

Comment: I was playing with something similar recently and got the impression that it's not a supported use-case in Bicep yet. Curious to see if you get an answer, though.

Comment: in your new `cosmos-db.bicep` do you still have the containers ? Could you past the full `cosmos-db.bicep`  ?

Comment: @Thomas yes, in `cosmos-db.bicep` I have both the database and containers resource. Edited the post to reflect that

Comment: You have 5 parameters defined in the cosmos-db.bicep file. you need to pass them from the main.bicep as well.

Comment: @Thomas I have variables defined at the top of the page which I pass into the parameters in main.bicep. For example, the databaseName param for cosmosdb in main.bicep. At the top of the file I have: `var databaseName = 'buying'`

Comment: but for example, you have `cosmosContainerName` param defined in the `cosmos-db.bicep` but you are not passing the parameter while calling the module from `main.bicep`.